# Mvc-Mini-Profiler: Why so many X-MiniProfiler-Ids?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using Mvc-Mini-Profiler (what a great product!). Using my ordinary web browser everything seems to work fine but as soon as I use my own http client (basic http 1.1 without cookie support) the amount of *X-MiniProfiler-Ids* in the http header increases. This happens quite rapidly and becomes quite many in a short amount of time (11kB and above of data).

Can the lack of cookies make Mvc-Mini-Profiler work this way or could anything be wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design I think. Though we could improve the implementation a bit.

The `X-MiniProfiler-Ids` need to be "consumed", they only show up when profiling is enabled. The reason it works this way is so you can profile `POST` and redirects.

We probably should set some clear upper limit there (like 20 or so) - please post a bug for that.

However, since you never really plan to consume any profiling blocks for you HTTP client, I would recommend abandoning profiling *if* the useragent is your HTTP client.

You can do this by adding a conditional before:

```
// don't run if UserAgent is "my http client"
if(notMyUserAgent)
   MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, bug reported as [#99](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=99)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to override the SqlServerStorage class and default the UserHasViewed field to true.  This will keep the `X-MiniProfiler-Id` string down to a minimum.

```
public class MvcMiniProfilerStorage : SqlServerStorage
{
    public MvcMiniProfilerStorage(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Stores  to dbo.MiniProfilers under its ;
    ///     stores all child Timings and SqlTimings to their respective tables.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Save(MiniProfiler profiler)
    {
        const string sql =
            @"insert into MiniProfilers
        (Id,
         Name,
         Started,
         MachineName,
         [User],
         Level,
         RootTimingId,
         DurationMilliseconds,
         DurationMillisecondsInSql,
         HasSqlTimings,
         HasDuplicateSqlTimings,
         HasTrivialTimings,
         HasAllTrivialTimings,
         TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds,
         HasUserViewed)
select       @Id,
         @Name,
         @Started,
         @MachineName,
         @User,
         @Level,
         @RootTimingId,
         @DurationMilliseconds,
         @DurationMillisecondsInSql,
         @HasSqlTimings,
         @HasDuplicateSqlTimings,
         @HasTrivialTimings,
         @HasAllTrivialTimings,
         @TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds,
         @HasUserViewed
where not exists (select 1 from MiniProfilers where Id = @Id)";
        // this syntax works on both mssql and sqlite

        using (DbConnection conn = GetOpenConnection())
        {
            int insertCount = conn.Execute(sql,
                new
                    {
                        profiler.Id,
                        Name = Truncate(profiler.Name, 200),
                        profiler.Started,
                        MachineName = Truncate(profiler.MachineName, 100),
                        User = Truncate(profiler.User, 100),
                        profiler.Level,
                        RootTimingId = profiler.Root.Id,
                        profiler.DurationMilliseconds,
                        profiler.DurationMillisecondsInSql,
                        profiler.HasSqlTimings,
                        profiler.HasDuplicateSqlTimings,
                        profiler.HasTrivialTimings,
                        profiler.HasAllTrivialTimings,
                        profiler.TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds,
                        // BUG: Too many X-MiniProfiler-Id headers cause
                        // Firefox to stop all requests
                        //
                        // This hack marks all entries as read so that
                        // they do not end up part of that header.
                        HasUserViewed = true
                    });

            if (insertCount > 0)
            {
                SaveTiming(conn, profiler, profiler.Root);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string Truncate(string s, int maxLength)
    {
        return s != null && s.Length >
                    maxLength ? s.Substring(0, maxLength) : s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever solution, but does this require me to use an sql storage? Also, this prevents the user agents that can handle a large amount of x-mini-profiler-ids from operating "normally".

Comment: This approach could be used to override the MemoryStorage also, I just happened to post this code from my project.  However, storing the data in a database does have its advantages [MVC Mini Profiler Dashboard](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler-dashboard/).

Comment: To answer your second question: Yes, it would prevent normal functionality on clients that can handle the large number of x-mini-profiler-ids.  Your other option would be to fork the Mvc-mini-profiler and make the fix to the original code or remove the x-mini-profiler-id headers for clients that can't support them :(